# Mui Datepicker value changes to previous date of selected date in React JS

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, datepicker

Expected Behaviour:
The `datepicker` must be null at initialization and while the user selects a date the value should be the same
`const [value, setValue] = useState(null)`
Instead of setting initial value as null setting a new Date displays this correct Date
`const [value, setValue] = useState(new Date())`
[see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LSomK.png)

Actual Behaviour:
Instead of the selected date being set as a value, It sets the incorrect date
[see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CFv6G.png)

Question:
I'm using [Mui v5](https://mui.com/x/react-date-pickers/getting-started/)
Is there a way to fix this? Thanks in advance

Here is my Code:

```
const [date, setDate] = useState(dayjs());

<LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDayjs}>
    <DatePicker
       label="Report Date"
       inputFormat="DD/MMM/YYYY"
       value={date}
       onChange={(newValue) => {
         setDate(newValue);
       }}
       renderInput={(params) => (
         <TextField
          {...params}
          color="info"
          inputProps={{
            ...params.inputProps,
            readOnly: true,
          }}
          />
       )}
       shouldDisableDate={disableWeekends}
    />
</LocalizationProvider>
```

Comment: Can you provide some of your code using `Mui`?

Comment: I had provided the code @mikenlanggio

Comment: @Lokkesh, did you check the printed value with your time zone? I'm not sure it is incorrect. Try putting the string value in an online site that parses epoch time and instead of the string value, print using Date getTime method for the millis. Example site: https://www.epochconverter.com/

Answer (score 1):

Try this solution, We just need to format the date to get the required date.

```
const [date, setDate] = useState(dayjs(date).format("YYYY-MM-DD"));
```

Comment: Thanks for the response @Ahmad, But I have already found the solution by setting `useState(dayjs(null))`